# A red cross is appearing on pom.xml file and it shows missing artifacts in dependencies

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have started working on maven a project . when the project is built , a red cross appears on my pom.xml file, how to resolve the dependency issue?

I already tried changing the jersey version to 1.8 and 1.19.1 as told in some answers, But the cross isn't going even after refereshing.

```
    <dependencies>                              // showing error
          <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>                       //showing error
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>                   //showing error
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: cmd+shift+a / ctrl+shift+a -> "Reimport all maven projects"?

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Have you tried running maven from the console? Do you have some kind of error log for the download failures?

Comment: you pom file is not generated properly, you need to fix the pom file generation. How are you generating the pom file?

Comment: Here is the Pom file of Glide Library. Have a look https://dl.bintray.com/sam-a-judd/maven/com/github/bumptech/glide/glide/3.6.1/

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your top-level project (not on the pom.xml file) in the Project Explorer view.
From the menu, choose Maven > Update project.
Make sure ForceUpdate of Snapshots/Releases is checked, and click OK
You'll see a progress indicator in the lower-right-hand corner of the application window.  When the update completes, you should be able to generate code normally, and the error markers should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I added below tags in pom.xml and the problem has been solved.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <exclude>**/*RunnerNew2.java</exclude>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
```